# Use promise instead of deferred?

Tags: angularjs, promise, deferred

I am using Angular JS in salesforce visualforce page. I wrote this code to fetch some information from server. It is an asynchronous call.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(  //You can related this with any asynchronous service
        '{!$RemoteAction.somepage.someMethod}',
        param,

    function(result,event){
        if(event.type=='exception'){
            deferred.reject(event.message);
        }
        else{

            deferred.resolve(result);
        }
    }
);

return deferred.promise;
```

Now someone said to me that "Use promise instead of deferred" (but didn't explain why.) This code is working absolutely fine but it seems like some anti-pattern way of doing this (I'm not sure how but i read it somewhere.). Now i saw many documents and resources and tried to figure out what is the best approach to do this.

Can you please explain **why it is not a good approach**? Also **how can i rewrite this code with best approach**?

It would be really helpful if you provide your answers in simple language as i am quite new to Angular also i have been to many links so please don't throw more links to me. Thanks.

**Edit 1:**

I tried to implement the [ES6 implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) but in the `.then` function when i am simply updating a variable it is not running the digest cycle means changes are not reflecting on the UI but it working perfectly fine with my code and code provided by @smnbbrv. can you please provide why it is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything bad in deferring (as long as this is kinda same promise in the end) however it is not a part of ES6 Promise standard / implementation. That's why at the moment you want to migrate from $q to native promises you won't be easily able to do so.

How to change your function: the very first example [from here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) is fully applicable to your case

```
return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
   Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(  //You can related this with any asynchronous service
          '{!$RemoteAction.somepage.someMethod}',
          param,

      function(result,event){
          if(event.type=='exception'){
             reject(event.message);
          }
          else{

             resolve(result);
          }
      }
);
```

Comment: Thanks @smnbbrv for the answer. Can you please explain how it is a better approach then previous also if you can add detail about the ES6 Promise standard / implementation and why i "won't be easily able to do so" that would be really great.

Comment: The approach is the same. `Now someone said to me that "Use promise instead of deferred" (but didn't explain why.)` You should ask the person who told you that. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise for ES6 promise implementation

Comment: That is a long story ;) ....Anyway i implemented ES6 promise implementation but in the `.then` function when i update some variable it doesn't reflect the changes on the UI, means it is not running the digest cycle, can you tell me why it is happening? It is working fine with above two cases. I have added this detail in my question as well.

Comment: `$q` has bindings for angularjs. Native promises don't. In angular2+ this is not a problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think its all down to massive bloated pieces of software trying to shave off loading times, using `Promise.resolve()` limits your ability to use promises...compared to pushing them all into a promises array and then deferring that.

```
var service = {
getData:getData
}
return service;

function getData(){
  getDataFromServerFunction
       .$loaded()
       .then(function (data){
          deferred.resolve(data);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```